# singleton pattern for microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

As per definintion of singleton pattern "
Ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it.
Encapsulated "just-in-time initialization" or "initialization on first use"."
How to create a Singleton object for distributed microservices using spring?

Comment: Singleton is a design (anti-)pattern, microservice is an architecture. 2 different levels

Answer (score 0):

A Microservice can have one to many endpoint routed to a service which actually runs the business logic and replies back the end result via Controller. In reality these micoservice components run inside a container. Now if you want just one specific container for that service then don;t scale it. If it is deployed to run on kubernetes then make run like a daemonset. These are just the references that you can do that will make it act like a singlton container.

Comment: If we don`t scale the service, there might be a chance that if this service goes down then there is no way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Singleton objects, you mean an instance of a class inside a microservice?

That's what Spring does: every Spring Bean is a Singleton by default.

That is: unless you have multiple instances of the java process, of course